# Can't rebuy an autorenewable subscription after user cancels it

Tags: swift, subscription, in-app-subscription

A user bought an autorenewable and cancelled it before the next renewal/expiration date.
Apple Server Side Notification catches this and sends the correct "EXPIRED" tag. Problem is user now wants to resubscribe with the same subscription product.

Code shows the purchase is successful and passes by the "purchased" case of the updatedTransaction delegate method and is successfully verified with the https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt url. But nothing gets sent to APSSN. And the new purchased subscription doesn't show in the readableReceipt.

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well. How did you solve it?